# Codeigniter : set_value() method for input type file is not working

Tags: codeigniter

set_value() method for input type file in codeigniter is not working. Can any one please help me.

view page -

uri->segment(2), $attributes); ?>

### Upload your image

" alt="your image" height="180" width="180" />

Thanks

Comment: did you load the form helper? $this->load->helper('form'); Otherwise post the controller and view code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
$data = array(
      'name'        => 'name',
      'value'       => 'abc',
      );

echo form_input($data);
```